¿Por que mi sitio web funciona a la perfección en mi servidor local (Xampp) pero cuando lo subo al hosting se duplica el contenido de una pagina
Cuando accedo al sitio web desde el hosting, se duplica el contenido de un archivo y al momento de ejecutar un script hecho en Ajax, se ejecuta dos veces también. El sitio web está programado en HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, Ajax jQuery, PHP y MySql (El siguiente codigo muestra capturas del problema)
Adjunto el enlace al sitio web -> https://www.beta.randworld.online


<img src="https://i.imgur.com/sAEkFS0.png">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/aRiMyya.png">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/pGWZKzG.png">




Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! El codigo debe estar en la pregunta, no en un enlace externo...

Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor aca. Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.
